# While loop ends prematurely

Tags: c#, list, while-loop, parent-child

I am trying to create a program wherein the CommonCharacters Student and HonorsStudent (child classes to CommonCharacter) "battle" each other by trying to get one another a lower test score. In my Main class (seen below) I am trying to simulate this "battle" between the characters but I am having trouble getting the characters to continue "battling" until all but one is left. I used the Count property of  in the while statement's condition so that it would loop until the count reaches 1. Because the loop ends after 3 runs, there's never a chance for me to remove objects from the . (HonorsStudents are removed when their afterScore is <= 50 and Students are removed when their afterScore is <=25).

Is there something wrong with my while loop?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<CommonCharacter> characters = new List<CommonCharacter>();
        characters.Add(new Student("Sarah", "female", 1));
        characters.Add(new Student("Kevin", "male", 2));
        characters.Add(new HonorsStudent("Matthew", "male", 3));
        characters.Add(new HonorsStudent("Gwen", "female", 4));

        // This will be used to choose a character to "battle" at random from the List of characters
        Random random = new Random();

        while(characters.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach(CommonCharacter CommonCharacter in characters)
            {
                int randomStudent = random.Next(characters.Count);

                // This makes sure there is no instance where a student "attacks" themself
                if (CommonCharacter.Name == characters[randomStudent].Name)
                {
                    random.Next(characters.Count);
                }
                else
                {
                    int points = CommonCharacter.TakeTest();

                    if (points > 0)
                    {
                        int afterScore = 100 - points;
                        Console.WriteLine(CommonCharacter.Name + " reports " + characters[randomStudent].Name + " for cheating and loses them " + points + " points.");
                        Console.WriteLine(characters[randomStudent].Name + " now has a test score of " + afterScore);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    else if (points == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(CommonCharacter.Name + " reports " + characters[randomStudent].Name + " for cheating but the claim is dismissed.");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            // This loop checks if any Students have fled
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if (characters[i].HasLeftClassroom() == true && characters[i].Position == "student")
                {
                    characters.RemoveAt(i);
                    Console.WriteLine(characters[i].Name + " has received below a 25 and has left the classroom.");
                }
            }

            // This loop checks if any HonorsStudents have fled
            for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (characters[i].HasLeftClassroom() == true && characters[i].Position == "honors student")
                {
                    characters.RemoveAt(i);
                    Console.WriteLine(characters[i].Name + " has received below a 50 and has left the classroom.");
                }
            }

            break;
        }
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at the beginning of the while loop and ran through a few lines to see what's going on?

Comment: @Tdorno, yep. I put it right at the beginning and stepped through the entire program. The Count property reads "4" throughout the entire program. (This doesn't surprise me because none of them reach scores that would force them to flee). But it stops after 4 "battles".

Comment: It actually looks to me like it might never end.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, oops. I was fiddling around with it for a bit and forgot to undo its removal.

Comment: During your first for loop, you have the possibility of editing the characters list. This would edit the indexes that get checked during the second for loop and could possibly be an issue for you. You should be removing from a copy of the original array as opposed to the actual array you are iterating through.

Comment: And after your edit, it will finish after the first loop.

Comment: @JosephBisaillon you're right. The first for loop was meant to have the conditions (int i = 0; i < 3; i++). But this doesn't change the loop's premature end.

Comment: You really need to rethink your logic here. For example, why are the values 25 and 50 not embedded in to `Student` and `HonorsStudent` classes? Also you have a good chance to regenerate the same random number inside your check for a duplicate number.

Comment: @DavidG Those values are embedded into the Student and HonorsStudent classes. The HasFledClassroom() method is a bool that returns true or false depending on the score. And yes, I've noticed that I sometimes get the same randomly generated number. But I thought it was better to create one random object than to create multiple.

Comment: You can create as many random numbers as you like, you might still get collisions.

Comment: While we're reviewing this code anyways I note that the pattern `if (x == true)` is a common sign of a novice programmer. This means "if it is true that x is true", which is a needlessly complex way to say "if x is true".  Just `if(x)` is fine if x is a `bool`.

Comment: Try using a while loop to keep grabbing random indexes until you no longer have a duplicate student. Also, I don't see you doing any logic with that randomly generated student other than just printing out his name.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop ends with a `break` statement. A break immediately terminates a loop. If you don't want your loop to terminate, do not write a break statement.

Get in the habit of stepping through your code **line by line** with a debugger, and *carefully* examine **every single line**. Getting in that habit will enable you to find defects like this yourself.

I note also that there is a statement consisting solely of a call to `Next` but that discards the result. This is almost certainly wrong; the method is only useful for its result!

There are possibly a lot of bugs here. Again, get into the debugger, go *line by line*, and verify that every line does *exactly what you meant it to do*. Since at least one of the lines does not do what you meant it to do, that's the bug.

Comment: Without the break statement it never ends ;-;

Comment: @corinne: Your question is the statement "while loop ends prematurely". I'm answering the question as stated, which I assumed was "why does my loop end prematurely?" Did you have a different question?

Comment: @EricLippert Oh, sorry about that. I think I understand now why my program never ends without the break. I think my variables aren't updating  which prevents items from being removed from the list. That's a separate question entirely. I'll just look at my code more extensively.

Comment: @corinne: When debugging programs, try to focus on the causes of your bugs, not the symptoms.  The first step in fixing the issue , "my loop never ends" is not, "add a break statement at the end," it is, "figure out why my loop never ends." Playing bug whack-a-mole tends to introduce even more bugs.  E.g., [programming by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).